# Why there is not function name after @@ when I use jgit to get difference?

Tags: git, diff, jgit

When I use jgit to acquire the difference between two files， I can get deference like this:

```
diff --git a/src/core/ngx_output_chain.c -Wsrc/core/ngx_output_chain.c
index 554fe1b..6bb463a 100644
--- a/src/core/ngx_output_chain.c
+++ -Wsrc/core/ngx_output_chain.c
@@ -377,8 +377,9 @@
             dst->in_file = 0;
         }
```

but there is not a function name after @@ like I use git diff.

How can I get the function name when I use jgit?

Answer (score 1):

There's no function name in diffs produced by `jgit` because, well, this feature is not supported by `jgit`.

Relevant lines from [org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/diff/DiffFormatter.java](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/b601e88738945b3861b99283173e31daf924227d/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/diff/DiffFormatter.java#L820-L843):

```java
protected void writeHunkHeader(int aStartLine, int aEndLine,
        int bStartLine, int bEndLine) throws IOException {
    out.write('@');
    out.write('@');
    writeRange('-', aStartLine + 1, aEndLine - aStartLine);
    writeRange('+', bStartLine + 1, bEndLine - bStartLine);
    out.write(' ');
    out.write('@');
    out.write('@');
    out.write('\n');
}
```

You can raise an issue on the [bug tracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JGit&rep_platform=All&op_sys=All) and maybe try to [implement this feature yourself](http://www.eclipse.org/contribute/) if you would really like it.